# Different output on changing the position of fgets() function

Tags: c, loops, file-handling

The output is correct when fgets() in included in the while loop, but taking it outside makes it an infinite loop. Can anyone explain why?

```
main() 
{
    FILE *fp=fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    char s[100];
    fgets(s,50,fp);
    while(s!=NULL) //infinte loop
        puts(s);
    /* while((fgets(s,100,fp))!=NULL)
          puts(s);
       This runs fine */
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: see my answer bellow. `fgets` reads a line from the stream tell `\n` or the limit chars have been reached. when fgets reach the `eof` it will return `null`. see my inline comments

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  First because it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Second because the function `main()` (for all C language valid signatures) returns a `int`

Comment: the array `s[]` will NEVER be equal to NULL, so the posted code contains a logic error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s!=NULL` compares the address of the array s against NULL, which will never match.

`while(fgets(s,100,fp))!=NULL)` compares the return of `fgets()` with NULL, which is NULL on EOF or error.

Search for:

```
man page fgets
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code 1**

```
main() 
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    FILE *fp=fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    if(!fp)
    {
        /*error occured during fopen()! abort*/
        printf("Error while openning the file!\n");
        return 1;
    } 
    char s[100];
    fgets(s,50,fp);   /*1*/

    while(s != NULL)  /*2*/
    {
        puts(s);      /*3*/
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

**Code 2**

```
main() 
{
    FILE *fp=fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    char s[100];
    while((fgets(s,100,fp)) != NULL) /*1*/
    {
        puts(s);                     /*2*/
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

In **Code 1**, when you reach point `/*1*/` your buffer `s` in not empty and contain some string (its not `null`). so you are entering the `while loop` with `s!=null` then in `/*3*/` you are printing this in the stdoutput and return to point `/*2*/` to ask if `s != null` and getting again the same answer that `s` is not `null`. hence you are stuck in this infinite loop forever.

In **Code 2**, In point `/*1*/` you are redaing a line from the input stream and ask if its not `null`. `fgets()` Upon successful completion, `fgets()` shall return `s`.  If the stream is at `end-of-file`, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and `fgets()` shall return a `null pointer`.  If a `read error` occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, `fgets()` shall return a `null pointer`, and shall set `errno` to indicate the error. In some point you will reach the `eof` and `fgets()` will return null and then you will exit the loop. for further reading please refer to man pages in the [link](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html)

Comment: You should at least check if `fopen` fails

Comment: @Jabberwocky - thanks for the comment. i am not correcting or fixing all code problems, i have just concentrained on his question. anyway thanks for the comment. i will add it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for (and handles) errors from `fopen()` and from `fgets()`
4. Eliminates the use of 'magic' numbers
5. includes the needed header files
6. contains a valid signature for `main()`
7. passes the proper parameters to `fgets()`
8. includes a final call to `puts()` to assure the output stream buffer is flushed to the terminal
9. incorporates my comments to the OPs question

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_LEN 100

int main( void ) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( "myfile.txt", "r" );
    if( ! fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read file: myfile.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char s[ BUF_LEN ];
    while( fgets( s, sizeof(s), fp ) )
    {
        puts( s );
    }
    puts( "" );
    fclose( fp );
}
```